# Absolute Position inside Relative when window Resized in Responsive design

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have 2 ***div*** elements.

1st ***div*** is larger and has ***position:relative***.

2nd ***div*** is set of Boxes inside 1st ***div*** and has ***position:absolute***.

When I resize the window to make it responsive, height of 2nd ***div*** grows and overflows the 1st ***div***.

I'm using ***jQuery*** to keep the height of the 1st ***div*** always larger than the 2nd ***div*** by looping through the 1st ***div*** childs and set **biggestHeight** to the 1st ***div***.

But, the height of 1st ***div*** is not increasing dynamically when I resize. I have to **Refresh** to see the effect.

I want the 1st ***div*** height to increase dynamically as I resize till $(window).width()>=576px.

Not sure, whether something like $(window).resize() might help.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var biggestHeight = "0";
    // Loop through elements children to find & set the biggest height
    $(".thumbnail-portfolio *").each(function(){
     // If this elements height is bigger than the biggestHeight
     if ($(this).height() > biggestHeight) {
       // Set the biggestHeight to this Height
       biggestHeight = $(this).height();
     }  });

    // Set the portfolio container height. 
    $(".thumbnail-portfolio").height(biggestHeight+200);
    $(".img-size-portfolio").height(biggestHeight+200);

});
```

> Here is the complete code: [1]: https://codepen.io/darthvadercodes/pen/erdGZM

**Update 1:**

Problem solved through @deebs answer.
Updating the **codepen** code with the solution I was looking for.

Thanks! everyone for your time.

**Solution:**

[https://codepen.io/darthvadercodes/pen/erdGZM ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe changing your layout may be best. Instead of having that image with a hard-coded value of 960px for height, you could remove that and add the property "[background-image](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)" to the div with class "container" that holds the boxes.  Because it seems to be the actual image that needs to be resized, and not the div.

Comment: The line: *add the property "background-image" to the div with class "container" that holds the boxes. Because it seems to be the actual image that needs to be resized, and not the div.*-   enlightened me. Exactly what I was looking for. No need of jQuery. ;)

Comment: Thanks !! for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, if the function is working as you intended, you need to trigger on re-size too, not just when the page is loaded. I'd wrap this into its own function, and trigger it on page load and on page resize, like so:

```
function setHeights() {
   var biggestHeight = "0";
   // Loop through elements children to find & set the biggest height
   $(".thumbnail-portfolio *").each(function(){
    // If this elements height is bigger than the biggestHeight
    if ($(this).height() > biggestHeight) {
      // Set the biggestHeight to this Height
      biggestHeight = $(this).height();
    }  });

   // Set the portfolio container height. 
   $(".thumbnail-portfolio").height(biggestHeight+200);
   $(".img-size-portfolio").height(biggestHeight+200);
}   

$(document).ready(function(){

   setHeights();
   $(window).resize(function() {
      setHeights();
   }); 

});
```

PS If you take this approach, you would need to drop the `biggestHeight+200`. Adding 200 every time leads to exponential size growth.

As per deebs answer, long term would be better to restructure the page, so you don't need to rely on absolute positioned elements and controlling the height manually.

Comment: I was aware that adding 200 to the biggestHeight increases it's height. But, even if I removed them previously the boxes in 1st Div still 
overflows to the 2nd Div. Need better logic.

Comment: Thanks! for your time.

Answer (score 0):

There is onResize event in javascript/jquery, try implementing it. https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I'll check that. Thanks !!